# Derby out of memory

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to load 100,000 records in the net beans database and end up getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE: XJ001, SQLERRMC: java.lang.OutOfMemoryErrorPermGen spaceXJ001.U
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at etl1.DBhandler.insertShuj1(DBhandler.java:150)
    at etl1.ETL1.shuja(ETL1.java:70)
    at etl1.ETL1.main(ETL1.java:32)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE: XJ001, SQLERRMC: java.lang.OutOfMemoryErrorPermGen spaceXJ001.U
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: A network protocol error was encountered and the connection has been terminated: the requested command encountered an unarchitected and implementation-specific condition for which there was no architected message (additional information may be available in the derby.log file on the server)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at etl1.DBhandler.insertShuj1(DBhandler.java:150)
    at etl1.ETL1.shuja(ETL1.java:70)
    at etl1.ETL1.main(ETL1.java:32)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: A network protocol error was encountered and the connection has been terminated: the requested command encountered an unarchitected and implementation-specific condition for which there was no architected message (additional information may be available in the derby.log file on the server)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.copyAsUnchainedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Sqlca.chainDeferredExceptionsToAgentOrAsConnectionWarnings(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Sqlca.getJDBCMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getMessage(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No current connection.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at etl1.DBhandler.insertShuj1(DBhandler.java:150)
    at etl1.ETL1.shuja(ETL1.java:70)
    at etl1.ETL1.main(ETL1.java:32)
```

i do get that the memory is not enough but how should increase it? really need help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running out of space in what is called the "permanent" heap.  Try `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` or `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`.  You might need to increase your regular heap also, for example, `-Xmx1024m`.